# Magento stock issue on credit memo

Tags: magento, stock

I have a Magento 1.7.0.2 website and every time i make a credit memo of an order the stock of that item is updated by 2 and not by 1. This is with every order.

Does anyone has an solution for this or where i can look for an solution?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you select the 'return to stock' option in the credit memo row area?  If I do that I get the right qty returned to stock.  Ie -> order 2 widgets ( dec's qty by 2 ), invoice, the credit memo only 1 with return to stock checked -> arrive at -1 qty of widget.

If I don't select the 'return to stock' option and do the credit memo than my inventory # doesn't change ( aka the above - credit memo only 1 return to stock not checked [ default ] -> arrive at -1 qty of widget ).